# How to convert LevelListDrawable into Bitmap or Icon

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I am getting this exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:
android.graphics.drawable.LevelListDrawable cannot be cast to
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
```

getting exception at this line

```
Drawable d= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.kb, null);

d.setLevel(3);   

Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
```

Comment: Please add some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get Bitmap from `Drawable`  folder like below Code :

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.kb);
```

Comment: Hi Chetan, Thanks for your help, But R.drawable.kb is a LevelListDrawable and I want to set level at runtime